# getting wrong id with laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

I have query below but it returns wront id.

```
$selectedAdmins = DB::table('organization_admins')
    ->whereIn('organization_admins.user_id', function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('project_admins.project_id', $id)->select('user_id')
                ->from('project_admins');
    })
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'organization_admins.user_id')
    ->join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select(
        'organization_admins.id as id',
        'users.email as email',
        'users.username as username',
        'profiles.mobilePhone1 as phone',
        'users.id as userId'
    )
    ->get();
```

What I need to get `as id` is `id of project_admins table`. I have tried to add `id` in `select()` part also replacing `organization_admins.id as id` with `project_admins.id as id` but no luck.

**Any idea?**

## Update

If I use `'project_admins.id as id',` I will get this error:

> message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'project_admins.id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `project_admins`.`id`
>   as `id`, `users`.`email` as `email`, `users`.`username` as `username`,
>   `profiles`.`mobilePhone1` as `phone`, `users`.`id` as `userId` from
>   `organization_admins` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` =
>   `organization_admins`.`user_id` inner join `profiles` on
>   `profiles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where
>   `organization_admins`.`user_id` not in (select `user_id` from
>   `project_admins` where `project_admins`.`project_id` = 2))"

Comment: This questions has already answered  here , check this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141487/laravel-4-eloquent-returns-wrong-id

Comment: @BloodyProgrammer i couldn't find my answer there. The problem with my query is that i don't join `project_admins` table i just function it for comparing therefore i cannot get it in my export select part.

Comment: what is error coming , please explain exact error when you run this query  .

Answer (score 0):

You can not get any fields from table `project_admins` because this information is within an subquery. You will have to restructure the query to achieve this.

You can start your query from `project_admins` though, and join organization admins. This way you will get access to project_admins as well: (SQL query only, you'll figure out how to do it in laravel):

```
SELECT
    project_admins.id as id,
    users.email as email,
    users.username as username,
    profiles.mobilePhone1 as phone,
    users.id as userId

FROM
    project_admins

LEFT JOIN
    organization_admins
ON
    organization_admins.user_id = project_admins.user_id

LEFT JOIN
    users
ON
    users.id = organization_admins.user_id

LEFT JOIN
    profiles
ON
    profiles.user_id = user.id

WHERE
    organization_admins.user_id IS NOT NULL /* only select rows where project organization admin exists */
AND
    project_admins.project_id = $id
```

*Please note that this is untested and since I don't know your tables structure may not be correct, it should get the idea across though.*